# Uploading to multiple buckets using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

Hey all I can't seem to find anything out there on the net except an old article that leads to a no longer existing page but I was wondering if paperclip supports uploading to multiple buckets on S3 at the same time.

I keep the same images in three locations(don't ask) and I am hoping to have them all upload using my current system when the files are dropped in. See an example of what I am looking to do below. These buckets all have the same credential I just need them in three spots.

```
storage: :s3,
s3_credentials: Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials }

def s3_credentials
  {bucket: "foo/bar", access_key_id: ENV["access_key_id"], secret_access_key: ENV["secret_access_key"]}
end
```

I tried procing a new s3_credentials and adding a second credential call with no luck.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better declare the bucket name separately from access_key_id and secret_access_key.

Try with the following instruction:

http://codetunes.com/2008/uploading-to-multiple-s3-buckets-with-paperclip-and-rails/

Comment: I just tried doing so, doesn't work for me. Even when I declare buckets and credentials separately it still only uploads the image to a single bucket.. This is also the site I was referring to when I said it leads to a no longer existing page. The download link goes to a 404 on that page.

Comment: @RyanPytleski There is a github link in the comment of that post. PaperclipExtended is there now.

Comment: Sure enough there seems to be a github for it out here, I am going to go play with that. I will report back if it still works since it is pretty old. Thanks!

Comment: This code does not seem to be working, I'm trying to write something myself now, if I can fix it before someone else posts I will put my code up.

Comment: I actually used a different work around as I could not find a way to make this work using the actual Gem, I instead wrote code that connected directly to each instance I wanted to upload the files into and then uploaded each set into the correct spots each time the proc was called.